# Blogger: how get post label in java-script variable

Tags: javascript, blogger

In bogger: I want to get the post label in the javaScript variable. but can't find a proper method. Can anyone help me?

want to get post(currently open) label in the variable for further functionality. for example like to show related post using label value in the sidebar or any place where we want to display. for the following [website](https://online-coding-courses.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

To get post label in a JS variable try this

```
var label = document.querySelectorAll('.post-labels a')[0].textContent;
```